# Symbols: How does implicit string conversion work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, ecmascript-6

Reading the documentation on `Symbol`s in JavaScript, and also testing in a few environments (Chrome, Firefox, Node.js), I've realized that my understanding of implicit string conversion is flawed.

I was always under the impression that the object's `toString()` method was called when attempting to convert to a string, and if that function didn't return a primitive, then it called the object's `toPrimitive()` method, then if that didn't work it would type-error. However, this explanation fails to cover the `TypeError` that `Symbol`s throw:

```js
var sym = Symbol("test");

try {
  console.log(sym + "ing");
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
```

But it's apparent that `Symbol`s have a valid `toString()` method. So why isn't it called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that an objects `toString` method is called when doing implicit string conversions. However, [as the spec states](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring), implicit string conversions on symbols cause a `TypeError`.

As [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer put it](http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html):

> Given that both strings and symbols can be property keys, you want to protect people from accidentally converting a symbol to a string.

Comment: This doesn't _really_ answer my question: How do `Symbol`s implement the ability to type-error and circumnavigate the default workflow of an implicit type-conversion?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The simple answer is "because the spec says so". The real answer would be that engine implementors must follow the spec so they implement something in their internals that checks for if a `Symbol` is involved in a string type conversion then throws the exception. The `Symbol` itself doesn't handle this behavior.

Comment: So the reason it type errors isn't due to a mechanic accessible from JavaScript?