# Why does implicit Symbol to String conversion' lead to TypeError in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

There is a `.toString()` on `Symbol` in ES6 which returns the string representation of `Symbol`, but wondering why `'' + Symbol()` doesn't work (run this expression throws out `TypeError` which I don't expect)? Is the latter just calling `.toString()` on a new `Symbol` and append (`+`) it to empty string?

Comment: @Dai `'' + 123` works as implicit type conversion, but why `'' + Symbol()` doesn't work even considered as implicit conversion?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. What behaviour are you actually seeing? Do you get a `TypeError` or something else?

Comment: @Dai, sorry that the question caused confusion. Revised a little. I saw `'' + Symbol()` throws TypeError, and wondering why it does this because `Symbol().toString()` works.

Comment: when I try Symbol().__proto__.toString() it throw an error,maybe it can help to understand this... (I dont know the answer..)

Comment: Related: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/string-symbol

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34881085/1541563

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is the latter just calling `.toString()` on a new `Symbol` and append (`+`) it to empty string?

No actually, Symbols cannot be implicitly cast to strings, or numbers, although interestingly enough you can implicitly cast them to a boolean.

[MDN actually has a section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Symbol_type_conversions) on some of these pitfalls:

> **Symbol type conversions**
>
> Some things to note when working with type conversion of symbols.
>
> - When trying to convert a symbol to a number, a `TypeError` will be thrown (e.g. `+sym` or `sym | 0`).
> - When using loose equality, `Object(sym) == sym` returns `true.`
> - `Symbol("foo") + "bar"` throws a `TypeError` (can't convert symbol to string). This prevents you from silently creating a new string property name from a symbol, for example.
> - The "safer" `String(sym)` conversion works like a call to `Symbol.prototype.toString()` with symbols, but note that `new String(sym)` will throw.

---

This behavior is documented in the spec under the [abstract `ToString` operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring):

> **Argument Type:** Symbol
>
> **Result:** Throw a `TypeError` exception.

And similarly for [abstract `ToNumber` operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber):

> **Argument Type:** Symbol
>
> **Result:** Throw a `TypeError` exception.

To cast a `Symbol` to a string without a `TypeError`, you must use either the `toString` method, or `String()`.

Comment: Does implicit cast an object to string mean calling `Object.prototype.toString()` on the object?

Comment: @Thomson Yes, implicitly casting an object to a string will call the `toString` method, either on the instance itself if one is set, or from the prototype.

Comment: as your comment, implicit casting `Symbol` to `String` should success because there is a workable `toString()`on the `Symbol` instance (`Symbol()`)?

Comment: @Thomson Symbol's actually aren't Object's though, they are primitives, and they are explicitly designed to throw a `TypeError` instead of implicitly calling the `toString` method.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, He's asking **does the unintended boxing happen when you do symbol.toString()?** Or should you do String(symbol) to prevent boxing?

Comment: I think this is so interesting. Problem in there we don't know why Symbol implicitly convert to string. In there you say " This prevents you from silently creating a new string property name from a symbol, for example". But I think this is not true 
look - https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-topropertykey

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toString.

> The Symbol object overrides the toString method of the Object object;
>   it does not inherit Object.prototype.toString(). For Symbol objects,
>   the toString method returns a string representation of the object.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is why `'' + symbol` doesn't work.