# Why Symbols not convert string implicitly

Tags: javascript

Why `Symbol('test').toString()` works well, but I can't use `'' + Symbol('test')`?

It will throw Error:

> cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Why does the implicit type conversion not work? Why is the code not equal to `'' + Symbol('test').toString()`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean why implicit type conversion not works? Why the code is not equal to `'' + Symbol('test').toString()`

Comment: read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Symbol_type_conversions for explanation

Comment: Related: [Convert JavaScript Symbol to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944470/convert-javascript-symbol-to-string)

Comment: To be more specific that error functionality is added specifically and on purpose (from MDN): *"Symbol("foo") + "bar" throws a TypeError (can't convert symbol to string). This prevents you from silently creating a new string property name from a symbol, for example."*

Comment: This article does a pretty good job explaining, basically `.toString()` is totally for convenience: https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/ It's a primitive without a lot of adornment.

Comment: It’s because symbols can be used as property names without being strings. Having an implicit string conversion (since when you use anything else as a property name, it’s implicitly converted to a string) could be confusing.

Comment: @Ry- I think you are not true :) When object add key in this time engine check if key property is string then call ToString internal method but if Symbol return Symbol itself. 
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-topropertykey

Comment: @MuradSofiyev: That’s why I said “could be confusing”, not “would completely defeat the purpose of symbols”. (Or, alternatively, note the “else” in “when you use anything else as a property name”.) Many tools that existed before symbols could be relying on the assumption that the only valid key for an object was a string, so if you passed a symbol to one and it manipulated it as a string, you would silently get the wrong result if symbols could be implicitly converted to strings. Which is why they aren’t.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to ECMA-262, using the [*addition operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus) on a value of type Symbol in combination with a string value first calls the internal [*ToPrimitive*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive), which returns the symbol. It then calls the internal [*ToString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tostring) which, for Symbols, will throw a TypeError exception.

So calling the internal *ToString* is not the same as calling [*Symbol.prototype.toString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-symbol.prototype.tostring).

So I guess the answer to:

> Why does the implicit type conversion not work?

is "*because the spec says so*".

Answer (score 4):

You can, however you're not meant to do so by accident.

```
console.log(''+String(Symbol('My symbol!')))
// Symbol(My other symbol!)

console.log(Symbol('My symbol!').description)
// My other symbol!

console.log(Symbol.keyFor(Symbol.for('My other symbol!')))
// My other symbol!
```

> **Note:** `Symbol.keyFor` only works for symbols created via the `Symbol.for` function.
>
> `Symbol.keyFor(Symbol('My symbol!'))` will evaluate to `undefined`.
>
> You can also use `.description` to get the string value used to create the symbol.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/for
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/keyFor

Answer (score -2):

your type not string

```
'' + Symbol('test').toString()
```

you can check, Symbol is a new type in ES6

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

```
The Symbol() function returns a value of type symbol, .....
```

Comment: I think OP is asking why JavaScript gives an error rather than converting the `Symbol` to a string automatically like it does with numbers when concatenated, since it's `.toString()` method works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I mean why implicit type conversion not works? Why the code is not equal to '' + Symbol('test').toString()