# Cannot bind Javascript Symbol to HTMLElement.style

Tags: javascript

Why can I bind a JavaScript Symbol to everything except the `style` property of an HTMLElement?

https://jsfiddle.net/elgs/ftj9zx42/3/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id='a'></div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
const a = document.querySelector('#a');
a.classList._someSymbol = Symbol('some_symbol');
console.log(1);
a.style._someSymbol = Symbol('some_symbol');
console.log(2);
```

And here's the output:

> 1
>      (index):35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
>          at window.onload ((index):35)

Update:

The whole story is I'm writing a proxy that will attach a Symbol to every property as identifier in the get trap, this unintentionally included the style. I will eventually include only the properties that I'm interested in, that won't include the style. But now I got this error and I'm curious why this happened.

Comment: Why are you using 'style' like that??? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The whole story is I'm writing a proxy that will attach a Symbol to every property as identifier in the get trap, this unintentionally included the style. I will eventually include only the properties that I'm interested in, that won't include the style. But now I got this error and I'm curious why this happened.

Comment: well you should be using a data attribute. Style is a string so when you set it is is trying to set the property it tries to convert the Symbol to a string and it is throwing the error.

Comment: @epascarello a huge long conversation about style getter/setters was wiped out by an admin, including docs references that style values are expected as string. OP wants to get around that error with some magic

Comment: @epascarello what you said is logical and answers my question, thanks!

Comment: @charlietfl what I think makes sense is `it tries to convert the Symbol to a string `, which you never mentioned. Actually @epascarello didn't mention how `it tries to convert the Symbol to a string `? Using proxy? Or anything else?

Comment: @QianChen sorry not going down that rabbit hole again. The error is very clear

Comment: @charlietfl no, I didn't want to get around that error. What I wanted to know is why that error happened.

Comment: You are just getting back to trying to put a square peg in a round hole. It's as simple as a type check in the setter. We went there numerous times already

Comment: @charlietfl like I got an error saying something is broken, and I asked why it's broken, and you answered me because the error said it's broken, so it's broken.

Comment: Which setter? show me the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's browser dependent. As HTML is a standard (it is a series of guidelines on how a document should be interpreted by a user agent).

So, your above example does work in FireFox, but not in Google Chrome.
If you want to understand why, I recommend looking into the source code of your browser, which appears to be converting your symbol [toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425974/why-cannot-convert-a-symbol-value-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('#a');

a.classList._someSymbol = {};
a.classList._someSymbol = Symbol('some_symbol');
console.log(1);

a.style._someSymbol = {};
a.style._someSymbol = Symbol('some_symbol');
console.log(2);
```

I don't know why it works in this way .

Comment: Yeah! this didn't throw error! Other people may have missed the point why I asked this question. I was not asking how to set styles for an HTML element. I was wondering how style differs from classList in this case. Thank you for your example.