# How to convert array containing a Symbol to string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that could contain Symbol() item. Array.toSring brings an exception.

```js
const s = [10, 'abc', Symbol('test')].toString(); // this throws an exception
console.log([10, 'abc', Symbol('test')]); // this works
```

What is the best way to convert such array to a string (like console.log does)?

Comment: Relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425974/why-cannot-convert-a-symbol-value-to-a-string

Comment: You get error because you don't convert Symbol() to string , You convert string for object. It should const s = [10, 'abc', Symbol('test').toString()];

Answer (score 6):

`.map` the array, calling `toString` on each symbol first:

```js
const s = [10, 'abc', Symbol('test')]
  .map(val => typeof val === 'symbol' ? val.toString() : val)
  .join(',');
console.log(s);
```

To turn a Symbol into a string, you have to do so explicitly.

Calling `toString` on a symbol is permitted, because that invokes [Symbol.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toString).

In contrast, trying to turn the Symbol into a string implicitly, like with [`Array.prototype.join`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.join), (or `Array.prototype.toString`, which internally calls `Array.prototype.join`, or `+`, etc), invokes the [ToString](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring) operation, which throws when the argument is a Symbol.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can convert the symbol to string instead of converting the  whole array

```
const s = [10, 'abc', Symbol('test').toString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a small operation on the array before .toString() is called on the array. Something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = [10, 'abc', Symbol('test')];
  var test = [];
  for(item of fruits){
      if(typeof(item) === "symbol"){
          test.push(item.toString());
      }
      else{test.push(item)}

  }
  var x = test.toString();
```

The thing is we don't want to call .toString() method on each item of the array.