# Error when trying to explicitly convert symbol wrapper object to string

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

I tried the following in firefox web console.

```js
    var sow = (function(){ return this; }).call(Symbol());

    console.log(typeof (sow)); // object

    console.log(sow.toString()); // Works: Symbol()

    String(sow); // Does not work: Throws "TypeError: can't convert symbol to string"
```

For some strange reason the explicit conversion in the last statement does not work (throws error).

Why is that the case?

Note that `sow` is an object and that is has a `toString` function returning a string in it's prototype chain, so it should work by using that function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Symbols not convert string implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425974/why-symbols-not-convert-string-implicitly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that your definition of `sow` can be simplified to:

```
var sow = Object(Symbol());
```

which does the same thing as your code, when in sloppy mode.

When you call `String` with an argument of `value`, per [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string-constructor):

> a. If NewTarget is undefined and Type(value) is Symbol, return SymbolDescriptiveString(value).
>
> b. Let s be ? ToString(value).

Here, since you've wrapped the symbol in an object, its type is *not* a symbol; rather, it's an object, so `ToString` is called. This, when called [with an object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring), will first coerce the object to a primitive, then call `ToString` on it:

> 1. Let primValue be ? ToPrimitive(argument, hint String).
> 2. Return ? ToString(primValue).

But symbols cannot have `ToString` called on them; as you can see in the same table there, when passed a Symbol, `ToString` will throw a TypeError.

That's why `String(sow);` works. In contrast, when you do `sow.toString()`, you're calling `Symbol.prototype.toString` with a calling context (a `this`) of the object-wrapped symbol:

```js
var sow = Object(Symbol());
console.log(sow.toString === Symbol.prototype.toString);
```

Which does something somewhat different. [Symbol.prototype.toString](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-symbol.prototype.tostring) retrieves the underlying Symbol from the object, and then calls [SymbolDescriptiveString](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-symboldescriptivestring) with the Symbol, resulting in a string with the symbol's descriptive value (if any).

Note that a native Symbol *not* wrapped in an object does *not* throw when passed to `String` because the [String constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string-constructor-string-value) will *not* call the problematic `ToString` abstract method when the argument is a symbol.

```js
const sym = Symbol();
console.log(String(sym));
console.log(sym.toString());
```